# How is Haskell's seq used?

Tags: haskell, strictness

So, Haskell `seq` function forces the evaluation of it's first argument and returns the second. Consequently it is an infix operator. If you want to force the evaluation of an expression, intuitively such a feature would be a unary operator. So, instead of

```
seq :: a -> b -> b
```

it would be

```
seq :: a -> a
```

Consequently, if the value you want is `a`, why return `b` and how do you construct for the return of `b`. Clearly, I am not thinking Haskell. :)

Comment: If you look at the [(very poorly formatted) definition of `foldl'`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Seq), you see that you often just want to strictly evaluate some let-bound variable in `a` that you feed into your `b` value.

Answer (score 19):

The way to think about `` a `seq` b `` is not that it "evaluates `a`" but that it creates a dependency between `a` and `b`, so that when you go to evaluate `b` you evaluate `a` as well.

This means, for example, that `` a `seq` a `` is completely redundant: you're telling Haskell to evaluate `a` when you evaluate `a`. By the same logic, `seq a` with just one argument would not be any different than simply writing `a` by itself.

Just having `seq a` that somehow evaluates `a` would not work. The problem is that `seq a` is itself an expression that might not be evaluated—it might be deep inside some nested thunks, for example. So it would only become relevant when you get to evaluating the whole `seq a` expression—at which point you would have been evaluating `a` by itself anyhow.

@Rhymoid's example of how it's used in a strict fold (`foldl'`) is good. Our goal is to write a fold such that its intermediate accumulated value (`acc`) is completely evaluated at each step as soon as we evaluate the final result. This is done by adding a `seq` between the accumulated value and the recursive call:

```
foldl' f z (x:xs) = 
  let z' = f z x in z' `seq` foldl' f z' xs
```

You can visualize this as a long chain of `seq` between each application of `f` in the  fold, connecting all of them to the final result. This way when you evaluate the final expression (ie the number you get by by summing a list), it evaluates the intermediate values (ie partial sums as you fold through the list) strictly.

Comment: I am now thinking the dependency created by `seq` is redundant at least in the case of `foldl` as described above since the regular `foldl` already impose such a dependency constraint on `z'` by virtue of using it...it seems.

Comment: @George `foldl (\x y -> 1) undefined [2]` evaluates to 1, instead of trying to evaluate the `undefined`. By comparison, using `foldl'` errors out, since it does evaluate it.

Comment: @George One of the characteristics you are used to in other languages that does not apply to Haskell is this: a function application does not obviously "use" all the arguments in the application. In particular, just because the application `foldl' f z' xs` has `z'` as an argument does not *necessarily* (i.e. without inspecting the definition of `foldl'`) mean that `z'` gets used. This is where your argument about `z'` being used falls down: `z'` is an argument to a function, hence not necessarily used.